# Python script for graph api gives error on refresh in power bi

Tags: python, powerbi

I have a python script for fetching graph api data within power bi. Occasionally it gives the following error on refresh -

A problem occurred while processing your Python script. 
Here are the technical details: Process must exit before requested information can be determined.

Details:

DataSourceKind=Python

DataSourcePath=Python

A problem occurred while processing your Python script.

Here are the technical details: Process must exit before requested information can be determined.
ErrorCode=-2147467259
ExceptionType=Microsoft.PowerBI.Scripting.Python.Exceptions.PythonUnexpectedException

Even after extensive search haven't been able to find the reason for the same.

Steps already tried - 
    1. I have tried switching between anaconda and normal python installed.
    2. All the libraries are updated with the latest version.
    3. I have tried clearing the cache of internal power bi desktop version.
    4. The python script runs perfectly outside power bi.
    5. Used privacy level for the data source as public.
    6. I even uninstalled everything and reinstalled powerbi desktop version and also python and anaconda but the issue remains the same.
    7. Tried on a different system but the issue remains the same.

Comment: Did you install Anaconda or just Python?  Do you have pandas installed in your python instance?

Comment: I have installed both Python and Anaconda. The script is running in Power BI and also giving me desired output but when I refresh the data at random this error pops up

Comment: Pandas is also installed

Answer (score 1):

As of today the error does not appear for Python v3.6 but for higher version. Seems there has to be a fix from Microsoft's end. This is a workaround solution that I have found and also raised the concern with the microsoft team but haven't received a reply from their end as of now.

Comment: To reviewers: please notice that this is the OP answering their own question.